# jQuery and replacing contents of 200 divs as fast as possible

Tags: jquery, html

I have 200 divs which id's are divvi1 ... divvi200.

```
<div id="divvi1">Text 1</div>
<div id="divvi2">Text 2</div>
<div id="divvi3">Text 3</div>
...
<div id="divvi198">Text 198</div>
<div id="divvi199">Text 199</div>
<div id="divvi200">Text 200</div>
```

I also have 200 lines of JavaScript/jQuery code which will replace the old text of my divs with the new texts. Here is an example:

```
<script>$('#divvi1').html('Lots of HTML code and text dggssgsdgs...');</script>
<script>$('#divvi2').html('Lots of HTML code and text fddgdsg...');</script>
<script>$('#divvi3').html('Lots of HTML code and text asdsdadad...');</script>
...
<script>$('#divvi198').html('Lots of HTML code and text fdffsdfdf...');</script>
<script>$('#divvi199').html('Lots of HTML code and text dasdsad...');</script>
<script>$('#divvi200').html('Lots of HTML code and text hfhfhfhf...');</script>
```

Anyway, this feels not so good way. How should I really do the job? How could I modify and/or optimize my code?

Comment: Is `Lots of HTML code and text dggssgsdgs...` The same for each div? Where do you grab that "HTML code and text" from?

Comment: No, the text is different on each div. The text will come from a database.

Comment: so how are you saving the data from the database? Is it just an array or is it in an object? I would say Chris Hull's answer would be simplest if combined with the data from the database given that it's also in an array

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you will run into issues fast, especially when trying to maintain the code.

1. Is your text that you are trying to replace coming in from back-end or another data source? Or is it just static like you are suggesting in your example?

Either way I would look into getting the data into a more usable format such as an array or JSON object.

```
//Example array
var myText = [
    "Lots of HTML code and text...",
    "Lots of HTML code and text...",
    "Lots of HTML code and text...",
    "Lots of HTML code and text...",
    "..."
];
```

Once you have the data in something that be iterated your next challenge is how to get all the data to the DOM as fast as possible without lagging the browser with 200 .html() or .append() functions. Best suggestion I can give is look into a template engine, something like JSRender https://www.jsviews.com/, (easy to use and easy to setup).

From there you can send the array over to the template engine and let it do the heavy looping.

```
//Example JSRender loop
{{for myText}}
    <div>{{>city}}</div>
{{/for}}
```

Using the API of JSRender you will then be returned one large HTML string that you can then use in something like $(".divWrapper").html(returnedData);

At least this way you only minipulate the DOM in one swoop rather then hundreds of .html() functions.

Comment: Is commercial use of JSRender 100% free?

Comment: Yes, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt

Comment: Does your code replace the old contents of 200 div with new texts? I cannot see the replace function here.

Comment: The replace occurs at the .parent() level of the <div id="divv###" /> thus why I have the one $(".divWrapper").html(returnedData);

The "returnedData" would contain your 200 divs with the text you fed it from the array. Learn more in the JSRender API - https://www.jsviews.com/#fortag

Comment: Here is an example using a JSON object to loop through many keys of data. Your implementation will be much more simple as you use a flat array. https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/fmoegzao/

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a simple for loop and concatenate the index with the selector

```
for(var i=1;i<=200;i++){
    $('#divvi' + i).html('Lots of HTML code and text...');
}
```

Comment: The text cannot be the same on each div.

Comment: It's going to depend entirely on how the text needs to be matched up to each "#divvi" + i. If it's coming from a database, is it going to be the order it needs to replaced in? If so, then you can just iterate through that list as well.

Comment: Anyway, is the for loop + $().html the best and fastest way to replace contents of 200 divs?

Comment: .html() will still be a heavy call on the browser and this type of loop will be a large hit on CPU and memory. If your wanting to do it without performance in mind then it will be a possibility, but this is really ill-advised.

if you must do it this way then do it safer with one .html() hit.

    var htmlStr = "";
    for(var i=1; i <= myText.length; i++){
        htmlStr += '<div id="divv'+i+'">'+myText[i]+'</div>';
    }
    $(".divWrapper").html(htmlStr)

Comment: It should be fast without needing so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try querying all the divs contain `divvi` string
`$('div[id*="divvi"]')` and then call `.each`

Answer (score -1):

If the "HTML code and text" for each div comes from a database, i assume you're using php, in that case i suggest you to use a JSON object to save all 200 entries. Also, i'll assume you're using AJAX, since it would have no sense to use Javascript if you could directly send the whole HTML output.

```
<?php
    $my_divs_content = array(
        'Lots of HTML code and text dggssgsdgs...',
        'Lots of HTML code and text fddgdsg...',
        'Lots of HTML code and text asdsdadad...',
        // And so on
    );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDivsContent = <?php echo json_encode($my_divs_content); ?>;
</script>
```

Further below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div[id^='divvi']").each(function() {
        var index = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("divvi", ""));
        if (typeof myDivsContent[index] !== "undefined") {
            $(this).html(myDivsContent[index]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it really the best way to say 200 times $(this).html(myDivsContent[index]);?

Comment: No where do they state they're using PHP so this really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Anyway, I'm using PHP.

Comment: In the wise words of South Park... If you use a loop with .html(), "YOUR GONNA HAVE A BAD TIME"

Comment: @xms, you won't be repeating the `$(this).html(myDivsContent[index]);` 200 times. How familiar are you to Javascript, jQuery?

Comment: @googabeast, well, he actually needs to update 200 divs content automatically, so if you have a better idea, go ahead :)

Comment: @EduardoEscobar thats why you should read my post, you will see I have devised a solution in a usable format that doesn't kill the browser. ^-- look up. It's the post with the most up votes thus far :)

Comment: @googabeast, alright, i just wanted to stick to jQuery since i saw he's using `$` and `html()`.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar Please examplain more what the code is doing. It seems to me that with each div it says $(this).html... and for me that means that $(this).html... is said 200 times.

Comment: @xms, do you actually want to *simplify your code* or *optimize it* in terms of resource usage / load / processing time?

Comment: The code should be fast and I do not want to "kill" the browser.

Comment: Well you may want to replace `html()` with `innerHTML`, even the whole jQuery part may be replaced by native Javascript. If that still doesn't work for you, consider the fact that there is no way to not "kill the browser" by looping through 200 divs and update their contents with JS.